# Can the exit code of a subshell be captured when declaring a variable with process substitution?

Tags: bash, variables, error-handling, local, readonly

Assume `set -e` is active for all that follows.

This will exit non-zero:

```
x=$(false)
```

But, none of these will exit non-zero:

```
declare x=$(false)
readonly x=$(false)
local x=$(false)
```

If you want to declare a mutable variable you can just do `x=$(false)`.
But if you want a readonly variable you have to resort to something like this:
`x=$(false) ; readonly x`

However, if you are in a function and you want a local, readonly variable you cannot do

```
x=$(false) ; local -r x
```

since you will overwrite the global x.

You could do `local x=$(false)` and the try to inspect x manually to see if there was an error. Or, you might check for output on stderr. But, neither of these will work in all cases; and, they're cumbersome.

Is there any way to get the exit code from a process substitution when assigning the result?

Comment: What is wrong with `local x; x=$(false)`?

Comment: I meant to put ``x=$(false) ; local -r x``. But your suggestion indicates that ``local x; x=$(false) local -r x;`` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the status of the process substitution, the assignment must be the only thing performed by the statement.  In a statement such as `local x=$(false)`, the value returned is the status of local, which typically succeeds.  To create a local readonly variable in a function and check the assignment from a process substitution, you can do:

```
local x
x=$(false) || echo "assigment of x failed !!" >&2
readonly x
```